# Validating PHP form fields

Tags: php, webforms

I have set up a form which has a tick box on it as well as a few textareas to enter comments. I want the user to have to complete the textarea(tutorComment) if they tick the tickbox(alert)

EDIT : Here is my complete code

```
if( !strlen($_POST['tutorComments']) && isset($_POST['alert'] )){
echo "<h3>You must enter a reason why you have clicked the alert box</h3>";
exit();}
```

This worked fine until I added this bit of code at the top of my php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submited']))
```

Can i not use the isset twice? I'm a bit confused as to why the code has stopped working

Thanks in advance

Here is the complete code

```
    <! Code to check that the user has logged into to view this page !>

<!Connection details for connecting to mysql database!>
<?php


//Select which database you want to connect to



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Op Tech Database - Add Record</title>
</head>
<!Code to Create drop down menu's!>
<?php
//Code for collectiing values for Student Names drop down drop
$result1=mysql_query("SELECT studentID, studentName FROM students");
$options1="";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

    $id=$row["studentID"];
    $first=$row["studentName"];

    $options1.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$first\">".$first.'</option>';
    }

//Code for getting tutors names in drop down list
$result2=mysql_query("SELECT staffID, tutorName FROM staff");

$options2="";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

    $id=$row["staffID"];
    $first=$row["tutorName"];

    $options2.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$first\">".$first.'</option>';
}
  ?>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ex1.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css" type="text/css" />
<!Create HTML elements!>
<form name="myform" form method="post">
  <h1 align="center"><a href="both.php"><img src="colour_logo_400.jpg" alt="University Logo" width="400" height="185" /></a></h1>
  <h1 align="center">Dental Hygiene Operative Technique Database</h1>
  <h2 align="center">Welcome to the Dental Hygiene Operative Technique Database v1</h2>
  <p align="left">&nbsp;</p>
  <p align="left">Student Name</p>
  <p align="left">

    <! Drop Down Menu to get student names from database !>
    <SELECT NAME=studentName >
        <OPTION VALUE=0 selected="selected">
            <?php echo $options1?>
    </SELECT>  

  <p align="left">Tutor Name  
  <p align="left"> 
    <! Drop Down Menu to get tutor names from database !>
    <select name=tutorName>
        <option value=0>
            <?php echo $options2 ?> </option> 
    </select>
  <p align="left">
  <p align="left"><br>


    Procedure
    <input type="text" name="procedure"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['procedure'])) echo $_POST['procedure'];?>" />
    <select name=grade id=grade>
      <option value="">Grade </option>
      <option value="N" <?php if (isset($_POST['grade']) && $_POST['grade'] == "N") { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>N</option>
      <option value="B" <?php if (isset($_POST['grade']) && $_POST['grade'] == "B") { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>B</option>
      <option value="C" <?php if (isset($_POST['grade']) && $_POST['grade'] == "C") {   echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>C</option>
    </select>
    <p align="left">

 Student Reflection:
        <br>
        <textarea name="studentReflection" cols="75" rows="5"><?php if(isset($_POST['studentReflection'])) echo $_POST[             'studentReflection'];?></textarea>
  <p align="left">
        <SELECT NAME=professionalism>
          <OPTION VALUE="">Professionalism
          <OPTION VALUE="U" <?php if (isset($_POST['professionalism']) && $_POST['professionalism'] == "U") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>U</option>
          <OPTION VALUE="S" <?php if (isset($_POST['professionalism']) && $_POST['professionalism'] == "S") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>S</option>
          <OPTION VALUE="E" <?php if (isset($_POST['professionalism']) && $_POST['professionalism'] == "E") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>U</option>
        </SELECT>
        </SELECT>

      <SELECT NAME=communication>
        <OPTION VALUE="">Communication
        <OPTION VALUE="U" <?php if (isset($_POST['communication']) && $_POST['communication'] == "U") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>U</option>
        <OPTION VALUE="S" <?php if (isset($_POST['communication']) && $_POST['communication'] == "S") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>S</option>
        <OPTION VALUE="E" <?php if (isset($_POST['communication']) && $_POST['communication'] == "E") {
      echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>U</option>
    </SELECT>

        Alert:
        <input type="checkbox" value="YES" name="alert" >  
        <br>
        <br>

        Tutor Comments:<br>
      <textarea name="tutorComments" cols="75" rows="5"><?php if(isset($_POST['tutorComments'])) echo $_POST['tutorComments'];?>            
        </textarea>
  <p align="left">


<!Submit buttons for the form!>
  <input type="hidden" name="submited" value="true" />
  <input type="submit" value="Update Database"  name="submit"/> 
  <input type='button' value='Logout' onClick="window.location.href='http://address/php_sandbox/optech/dh/current/14june/logout.php'">  
  <p align="left">
    <?php
//Error Message to display if all the correct fields are not completed.


if(isset($_REQUEST['submited'])) {

$errorMessage = "This is the standard error message";

$options1 = $_POST['studentName'];
$options2 = $_POST['tutorName'];
$procedure = $_POST['procedure'];
$grade = $_POST['grade'];
$studentReflection = $_POST['studentReflection'];
$professionalism = $_POST['professionalism'];
$communication = $_POST['communication'];
$tutorComments = $_POST ['tutorComments'];


if(empty($_POST['alert']))
{
$_POST['alert'] = "NO";
}
$alert = $_POST['alert'] ;


//Code to check that the Student Name field is completed
if(empty($_POST['studentName'])) 
{
echo "<h3>You have not selected a student. Please go back and do so!</h3>";
exit();
}
//Code to check that the Tutor Name field is completed
if(empty($_POST['tutorName'] ))
{
echo "<h3>You did not select a tutor name. Please go back and select your name from the tutors list</h3>";
exit();
}
//Code to check that the Procedure field is completed
if(empty($_POST['procedure'] ))
{
echo  "<h3>You did not select a procedure. Please go back and enter the name of the procedure which you undertook</h3>";
exit();
}
//Code to check that the Grade field is completed
if(empty($_POST['grade'] ))
{
echo "<h3>You did not select a grade. Please go back and select your grade from the drop down list</h3>";
exit();
}
//Code to check that the Student Reflection field is completed
if(empty($_POST['studentReflection'] ))
{
echo "<h3>The student did not enter any comments for this procedure. Student reflection is required for each procedure. Please go back and enter any comments</h3>";
exit();
}
//Code to check if the tick box is checked that the tutor comment is entered

if( !strlen($_POST['tutorComments']) && isset($_POST['alert'] )){
    echo "<h3>You must enter a reason why you have clicked the alert box</h3>";
    exit();
}



//Code to connect to the database




$query= "INSERT INTO entry (entryID, studentName , tutorName , procedureName , grade , studentReflection , tutorComments,  professionalism , communication , alert  ) VALUES ('NULL', '".$options1."' , '".$options2." ' , '".$procedure."' , '".$grade."' , '".$studentReflection."', '".$tutorComments."' , '".$professionalism."' , '".$communication."' , '".$alert."'  )";


mysql_query($query) or die ('Error : Something fucked up' .mysql_error());


echo "<h3>The Database Has been updated. Thanks </h3></b>" ; 
}
?>
</FORM>
<p>  <a href="both.php">Enter another procedure </a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a form field called "submited"? What happens now? Do you get any error messages (make sure you have configured PHP to show error messages while developing).

Comment: I have a hidden button which is called "submited"?

The form now accepts submission that have the alert box ticked and has nothing in the tutorComment textarea which it should not do and did not do until I added the if(isset($_REQUEST['submited'])) code

Comment: A "hidden button"? If it is a hidden input you need to give it a "value". If it's a button, it will not be set unless it is clicked.

Comment: It does have a value and it is not this that is the problem. This is just a method to get the php to cycle through my conditions (if statements) once the submit button is clicked. All the other conditions work as they just check that the $_POST for the particular element of the form is not empty but the last one which evaluates if the tick box is clicked and if there is no text in the tutor comment does not work for some reason

Comment: Can we see more of the code? The whole form if you can, or just leave out the bits that are working.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code, I can't say what exactly but some possible problems to look at:

- looks like you're missing a `'?>'` at the top, on line before the DOCTYPE etc.
- Form has `no action=""` so put the name of the current php file or $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
- student names option and alert input don't have closing tags
- Try doing the isset on the submit button instead, no need for the hidden input:

`if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {`or  `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {`

If it's still not working try moving that whole block of code to the top before outputting the form.

- Instead of using empty() for this, just check that it's set or not:

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['alert']))
      $alert = $_POST['alert'];
  else 
      $alert = "";
  ```

or for short: `$alert = isset($_POST['alert'])?$_POST['alert']:"";`

- Instead of this:

  ```
  if( !strlen($_POST['tutorComments']) 
    && isset($_POST['alert'] )){
   echo "You must enter a reason why you have clicked the alert box";
   exit();
  }
  ```

write it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['alert'])){
    if(!strlen($_POST['tutorComments']))
    echo "You must enter a reason why you have clicked the alert box";
    // leave out the exit()
}
```

or try different tests such as: `if(strlen($_POST['tutorComments'])< 1)`  etc.

Comment: Hi . There may be some syntax errors as I did remove some of the code to do with connecting to my database.
I will give you suggestion a go and report back.

Comment: Hi Guys. Turns out that my original code did work but somehow the tutorComments field was being populated by something which was not visible and therefor when I thought there was nothin in the field there actually was. Problem solved. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Can you please click the accept link beside my answer if it helped?